# Participating in discussion

Tags: professionalism, communication, developer

I got a team, and i am new to the company. Sometimes they are in discussion of something that i am not aware of many things they talk, i feel awkward as all developer are brainstorming and i always have some work, even if i give my advice.
I am not "really" able to help them expect give them pointers. However when i need help, they really help me out like a pro.
How can i overcome this lack/guilt that i am not much capable of helping them as they are to me. Does this have negative impact on my probation and job?

Comment: Asking good questions is also participating. Listen carefully and ask good questions, and you may expose something they never thought of. (But try to be informed enough, and listen carefully enough, that your questions _are_ good questions.)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you're new, you're going to receive more help than you offer back. That is 100% expected. You have to familiarize yourself with new people, products, culture, code base, etc. If you have ideas or suggestions, definitely provide them, but unless you were hired to be the new super awesome expert, they're not expecting you to be the new super awesome expert.

My standard advice is to be gracious. Thank the people who are helping you. Make sure they know how much you appreciate it.

---

> Does this have negative impact on my probation and job?

We cannot answer that, however, I would expect not. If you're really unsure of yourself, talk to your manager. "It's been <6 weeks> and I'm still working on coming up to speed. Just want to get some feedback on how you think things are going?"

Leave it open ended. Don't bias you manager into thinking you're failing. Get their honest feedback first. The response might be, "You're doing awesome! You're way ahead of where I expected!" If their response isn't positive, work with your manager to come up with a plan to improve your onboarding.

---

Last, but not least, you may well be falling victim to [imposter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome). You're probably doing better than you think you are.

The times I've had people come to me concerned they're moving too slow or asking too many questions, they're almost always doing better than I expect. The people who are truly struggling tend to be blissfully unaware of their ineptitude ([the Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)).

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes be useful to make notes of points you don't understand. After the conversation is over, ask someone who seemed to understand was was going on to explain. That way, you only take up one person's time, not the whole group's.

Answer (score 1):

Ask away - especially in the early days. You may even find that you're asking questions that other people are too embarrassed to ask, because they've been there a while and it's just assumed that they know stuff.